# Offset function wont work to delete all visible cells besides headers

Tags: excel, vba

My code is working until I try to delete all visible cells (besides headers) after filtering. Can someone tell me why my offset command is giving me a application defined or object defined error?

I have tried just using rows, deleting visible cells, setting a range.

```
    'Filter target cell out and remove all other rows
    With targetSheet.Range(targetRangeName)
        .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="<>" & sourceCell.Value, Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Offset(1, 0).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
```

I want to delete all visible cells (besides headers) after filtering.

Comment: Are you sure AutoFilter returns at least one row to delete? The error may be caused by absence of any rows to delete after filter is applied.

Comment: Yes, it returns roughly 25/150 (loop will run around 10 times).

Comment: The offset is only deleting the first row after the `targetRangeName`.  I would suggest using a `Union` to remove all of the visible rows.  This link may offer some guidance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45363077/deleting-rows-from-filtered-range-via-macro.

Comment: I have had this exact formula work before, which is why it is strange.  I am just not sure why it isn't working here.  I can post the entire code if that will help.

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer, but break it up a bit to see if you can debug:

```
Dim rng As range

With targetSheet.Range(targetRangeName)

    .AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="<>" & sourceCell.Value, _
                Operator:=xlFilterValues

    Set rng = .Offset(1, 0)
    Debug.Print rng.Address

    Set rng = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    Debug.Print rng.Rows.Count

    rng.EntireRow.Delete

End With
```

**EDIT**: you can't offset a range by one row if it already reaches the last row in the sheet.  If all you really want to do is exclude a header row then you can do something like this:

```
Dim rng
Set rng = ActiveSheet.Columns(1)

Debug.Print rng.Address '>> $A:$A

'resize and offset to exclude the first row
Set rng = rng.Resize(rng.Rows.Count - 1, rng.Columns.Count).Offset(1, 0)

Debug.Print rng.Address '>> $A$2:$A$1048576
```

Comment: Hi Tim,  I am getting that the offset (1, 0) is an application defined or object defined error.  I shouldn't have to declare an offset function should I?

Comment: What's the range `targetRangeName` when it fails?  If that represents one or more complete columns, then you can't offset that by one row...

Comment: This represents the entire worksheet, essentially.  Does it need to be a single column (i.e. the column I am filtering by)?  When I try setting targetrangename to the column I am filtering and the field:=1 I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: The range is columns ("A:AM") and then the filter column is 17.

Comment: @ConnorSmith - its very efficient to work with *entire columns* of data when only *n* number of rows has actual data. Get the lastRow of used data and then work with that defined range. you're programs will be much happier :)

Comment: Scott, you have answered a lifelong question!  Thank you, sir!